# Add individual key to SessionStorage for forms created by ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript, session-storage

I have a problem with create individual sessionStorage key for forms.

This is my HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let obj of Objects; index as i">
    <form-deleted-obj [(formData)]="deletedObj[i]">
    </form-deleted-obj>
</ng-container>
```

This is my service

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FormDeletedObjService {

constructor (protected sessionStorageService: SessionStorageService,
    private router: Router) {
super(sessionStorageService, KeyFormSession.Form_Delete_Obj);
this.setRange(this.router, [DetailsNewTask.Task_Realization])
    }
}
```

KeyFormSession.Form_Delete_Obj - this is enum

In this way, I created key in sessionStorage with name 'FormDeleteObj'. But when I change something in forms, the sessionStorage data is overwritten. I need create specific key in sessionStorage for all forms created with ngFor loop, or created one key with data from all forms.
I try to pass to `super(sessionStorageService, KeyFormSession.Form_Delete_Obj);` additional id, but I have problem with types. Any idea or suggestion?

I have another idea about reach this by add <ng-template #formsName> to get in parent component data from forms, but I can't use this situation.